# Событие на нажатие кнопки мыши вне элемента управления. C#. Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, события

Как обработать событие одиночного и двойного нажатия кнопки мыши за границами элемента управления? Все события нажатия кнопки мыши привязаны к элементам, действуют только в их области.

Comment: У формы тоже есть события click и doubleclick

Comment: Они будут срабатывать только в области формы, мне надо, чтобы и за границей формы работало

Comment: Смотрите события потери формой фокуса

Comment: За границей формы нет, не выйдет. Мышиные события в другом приложении доставляются этому самом другому приложению.